# How to place the one element as checked among multiple elements coming from the backend

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, togglebutton, angular-ng-if

I want to place the one element as checked (based on the condition) from the loop of elements which are coming dynamically.

**.component.ts**

```
checked(sensorname){
    for (var i=0;i<this.sensorsarray.length; i++ ){   

    if(this.sensorsarray[i].name == this.sensors.name){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }

  }
```

and I have called the function in html as

**.component.html**

```
ul class="list-group" *ngFor ="let sensor of sensors;let i =index"  
(ngModelChange)="dataChanged(selectsensor)">
<div class="custom-control custom-switch" >

  <li class="list-group-item" style="padding: 5px;"  > {{sensor.name}}
    <span style="float: right;" >
    <input type="checkbox"  class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches{{i}}" (click)="dataChanged(sensor,i)">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches{{i}}">    </label>
  </span>
</li>
</div>
  
</ul>
```

So I want to place the on element as checked  by default based on the condition.

Comment: nice system.. thanks to the functions working together it was not difficult helping u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left a lot out it seems so I'll just make the `checked` function do the work assuming `sensor` is a list of elements

**.component.ts**

```
checked(sensorname){
  for (var i=0;i<this.sensorsarray.length; i++ ){
    if(this.sensorsarray[i].name == this.sensors.name){
      this.sensorarray[i].checked=true
      return true
    }
    else{
      this.sensorarray[i].checked=false
      return false
    }
  }
}
```